# How to access OrderItems for a specfic order via foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I am building an online shop to sell music. I have a problem with my ProfileView, where I want to show the customer his finished orders with the files that he has purchased.

Here are my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='product_files')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    soundkit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    licence_variation = models.ManyToManyField(LicenceVariation)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("cart:product-detail", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('staff:product-delete', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def is_soundkit(self):
        return self.soundkit

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse("staff:product-update", kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey("Order", related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    licence_variation = models.ForeignKey(LicenceVariation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title

    def get_raw_total_item_price(self):
        return self.licence_variation.price

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        price = self.get_raw_total_item_price()
        return "{:.2f}".format(price / 100)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='billing_address', blank=True, null=True,
                                        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='shipping_address', blank=True, null=True,
                                         on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reference_number

    @property
    def reference_number(self):
        return f"Order-{self.pk}"

    def get_raw_subtotal(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_raw_total_item_price()
        return total

    def get_subtotal(self):
        subtotal = self.get_raw_subtotal()
        return "{:.2f}".format(subtotal / 100)

    def get_raw_total(self):
        subtotal = self.get_raw_subtotal()
        return subtotal

    def get_total(self):
        total = self.get_raw_total()
        return "{:.2f}".format(total / 100)

    def get_order_item_set(self):
        return self.items.all()
```

Here is my Profile View

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profile.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            "orders": Order.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, ordered=True),
            'order_items': OrderItem.objects.all
        })
        return context
```

Obviously it is displaying all the OrderItems in my template, because I use the objects.all method, but I want to filter it, so that it only displays the OrderItems which belong to the correct order.

Can anybody help me with the correct way of filtering the OrderItems?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In the template, you could group the order items by order using the FK relation:

```
{% for order in orders %}
  <h3>{{ order }}</h3>
  {% for item in order.items.all %}
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But if you just want an ordered list of all the items by order, you could probably do

`OrderItem.objects.all().order_by('order')`